# How to set `ga_session_id` with google tag manager (GTM)?

Tags: google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I would like to set the `ga_session_id` that gets reported in google analytics (along with other event parameters) dynamically. With global site tag (`gtag.js`) I can make the following call to set the `ga_session_id`:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
   session_id: 'my_custom_session_id'
})
```

How can I accomplish the same thing in GTM?

Comment: What is the session_id in your example? Is it a custom dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Set the field `session_id` in the GA4 settings tag.